# Who is this super heroine?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero

This [T-shirt design](http://www.neatoshop.com/product/Super-BFFs2) shows five "Super BFFs".

**Who is the one on the far left?**

[image: T-shirt image]

I can identify (from the second left) Gamora, Power Girl, Black Canary and She Hulk, but who is the one on the left supposed to be?

Comment: Just in case you're planning on buying that for somebody, let me point out that a comic-book enthusiast might be annoyed that three of those characters are from Marvel, and two are DC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Spider-Gwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Gwen), a character from an alternate-universe where Gwen Stacy had the spider-bite.  She became rather popular, largely due to her costume design.

[image]

Comment: Second from left I'm pretty sure is Gamora, not Miss Martian too.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I wasn't too sure about the Miss M ident.  Edited in.